# Как получить элементы из вложенного списка?

Tags: python, list

Есть ли более красивое (правильное) решение, переложить элементы вложенного списка в обычный?

Список:

```
aaa = [['123', 'AAA'], ['456', 'BBB']]
```

Получить:

```
bbb = ['AAA', 'BBB']
```

Мой вариант:

```
bbb = []
for i, row in enumerate(aaa):
    bbb.append(aaa[i][1])
```

Comment: bbb=[ aaa[i][1] for i,row in enumerate(aaa) ]

Answer (score 2):

Простой, понятный и относительно быстрый вариант решения:

```
res = [x[1] for x in aaa]
```

---

Варианты для истинных <s>извращенцев</s> ценителей прекрасного:

```
res = list(list(zip(*aaa))[1])
```

(c) GrAnd:

```
res = sum(aaa, [])[1::2]
```

похожий по смыслу вариант:

```
from itertools import chain

res = list(chain.from_iterable(aaa))[1::2]
```

Comment: В копилку, эм... ценителей. :) `res = sum(aaa, [])[1::2]`

Comment: @GrAnd, неплохо)

Comment: Всем спасибо :)

Comment: @yadoti3776, [как принято говорить "спасибо" на SO (StackOverflow) ;)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814)

Comment: А как работает вариант res = sum(aaa, [])[1::2]? Что он делает?

Comment: @Vadim.M., выполните команду по частям (`sum(aaa, [])`, `sum(aaa, [])[1::2]`) и все станет понятно ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator

print(list(map(operator.itemgetter(1), aaa)))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]